# What is the meaning of the suffix “‑don”?

Tags: meaning, loanwords, suffixes

What are the meaning and origin of the suffix *‑don*, as in the words *pteranodon* and *megalodon*?

Comment: Wikipedia has a general reference of [Latin and Greek roots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Greek_and_Latin_roots_in_English).

Answer (score 6):

*-odon* (not just *-don*) means **tooth.**  It is a variation of the suffix *[-odont](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/-odont)*, which comes from *odon*, which is Greek for *tooth*.

*[pter](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pter-)[-anódōn](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pteranodon)* means *winged-toothless*; *megalodon* means *large-toothed*.  I learned Greek a while ago, and though I'm rusty, I recognized the words behind those names.

Comment: AH, makes perfect sense now. I can see the root in the word orthodontist! Appreciated!

Comment: @Gabe: Yes.  _Ortho-_ means _straight_ or _correct_; _-dont_ means _tooth_ (or _teeth_, in this case).  So an orthodontist is a "straight-toothist", or "tooth-straightener".

Answer (score 2):

The suffix is not -don but -odon... Look at the etymology for "*Ptenarodon*":

> ORIGIN modern Latin, from Greek pteron ‘wing’ + an- ‘without’ + odous, odont- ‘tooth.’

---

"*Odont*" still survives in Italian (I'm not aware about other languages), for example in the medical field "*[Odontoiatria](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odontoiatria)*" which treats about preventing/healing deseases that affect teeth, mandibles, gum, etc.

Comment: and it's related to Latin "dent-", and indeed to German "Zahn"  - yes, and English "tooth", though those are not so obvious.

Comment: @Colin: In italian teeth = denti :D

Answer (score 0):

It’s the Greek for tooth. *Megalodon* = big tooth. *Iguanadon* = lizard tooth.